# Python traceback at QGIS startup with QgsMapLayerComboBox in Plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, qt-designer, qgis-custom-widgets

I created a QGIS (2.14.8 LTR) plugin gui with QtDesigner and I would like to use a `QgsMapLayerComboBox`, cp. screenshot below (selected widget, settings at the right).

[image]

At QGIS startup, when loading the plugins I get the following traceback:

```
2016-11-02T15:27:40 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 306, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:/Users/Jochen/.qgis2/python/plugins\ALBeDa\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
            from .al_ba import AlBA
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/Jochen/.qgis2/python/plugins\ALBeDa\al_ba.py", line 29, in <module>
            from al_ba_dockwidget import AlBADockWidget
          File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/Jochen/.qgis2/python/plugins\ALBeDa\al_ba_dockwidget.py", line 43, in <module>
            os.path.dirname(__file__), 'al_ba_dockwidget_base.ui'))
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 210, in loadUiType
            winfo = compiler.UICompiler().compileUi(uifile, code_string, from_imports, resource_suffix)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\Compiler\compiler.py", line 139, in compileUi
            w = self.parse(input_stream, resource_suffix)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 933, in parse
            actor(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 772, in createUserInterface
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 224, in createWidget
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 461, in createLayout
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 504, in handleItem
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 461, in createLayout
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 504, in handleItem
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 224, in createWidget
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 224, in createWidget
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 461, in createLayout
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 504, in handleItem
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 461, in createLayout
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 504, in handleItem
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 224, in createWidget
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 224, in createWidget
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 461, in createLayout
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 504, in handleItem
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 461, in createLayout
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 504, in handleItem
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 461, in createLayout
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 504, in handleItem
            self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 750, in traverseWidgetTree
            handler(self, child)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 215, in createWidget
            self.stack.push(self.setupObject(widget_class, parent, elem))
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 177, in setupObject
            self.wprops.setProperties(obj, branch)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\properties.py", line 418, in setProperties
            prop_value = self.convert(prop, widget)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\properties.py", line 383, in convert
            return func(prop[0], **args)
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\properties.py", line 116, in _set
            expr = [self._pyEnumMember(v) for v in prop.text.split('|')]
          File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\properties.py", line 111, in _pyEnumMember
            raise AttributeError("unknown enum %s" % cpp_name)
        AttributeError: unknown enum QgsMapLayerProxyModel::PolygonLayer
```

Do I miss something in the configuration or do I not use this as intented? One explanation might be that there are no map layers at QGIS startup, but then how to use this at all (is the `QgsMapLayerComboBox` widget updated when adding layers or opening a new project)?

Comment: It might be an issue with dependencies because I couldn't reproduce the problem on a GNU/Linux machine. If it helps somehow, have a look at [my installed QGIS packages](http://downloads.tuxfamily.org/tuxgis/tmp/installed.png).

Comment: I believe there's an issue with accessing the Qgs* widgets under windows, from plugins anyway - it affected one of my plugins. In my case, though, I was able to revert to the standard Qt widget. [This issue](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13428) and the associated dev mailing list thread might be of interest

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same bug and I managed to solve it copying qgis_customwidgets.py file in the right place during plugin initialization appending to `__init__` function the following lines:

```
    import shutils        

    #check for qgis_customwidgets.py
    qgis_loc = os.path.abspath(os.environ["QGIS_PREFIX_PATH"])
    bad_loc =  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(qgis_loc,"python","PyQt4","uic","widget-plugins","qgis_customwidgets.py"))
    right_loc =  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(qgis_loc,"..","Python27","Lib","site-packages","PyQt4","uic","widget-plugins","qgis_customwidgets.py"))
    if os.path.exists(bad_loc) and not os.path.exists(right_loc):
        shutil.copyfile(bad_loc,right_loc)
```